# Delete Row and adjust sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I need help with the sql query below -

```
DECLARE
    cnt           NUMBER;
    tempid          NUMBER;
    mysection      VARCHAR2 (200);

BEGIN
    tempid          := 160645;
    mysection       := 'Sub-sub section A4';

    FOR x IN (SELECT * 
              FROM table1
              where templateID = tempID)
    LOOP
        SELECT COUNT (*)
        INTO   cnt
        FROM   table1
        where templateID = tempID;

        IF (cnt > 0) THEN

            UPDATE table1
            SET    parentid   = parentid - 1
              WHERE TO_NUMBER (parentid) > TO_NUMBER (x.parentid) and section = mysection;

            UPDATE table1
            SET    childid  = childid - 1
            WHERE  TO_NUMBER (childid) > TO_NUMBER (x.parentid) and section = mysection;

           delete from table1 where tmplateid = tmpid and section = mysection;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

END;
.
/
```

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a data which is in tree format. To explain further, in the screenshot, you can see that the "main section" has a parentId of 1 which is the childID of the section underneath main section, i.e., "sub-section". "Sub-section" itself has a parentID of 2, which is the ChildID of sections below "sub-section", i.e., sub-sub section 1 to sub-sub section 5.

The data table is structure like this -

- Col 1 is the templateID which is the ID of the template that contains
  all the section.
- Col 2 is the parentID of all sections. ParentID is a sequential number
- Col 3 is the childid of all sections
- Col 4 is the text of all sections

What I want to do is delete "Sub-sub section A5" and automatically adjust the ParentID sequential number and the childID col numbers. I have provided example in the attached dataset. [image]

Comment: Could you explain why do you need to adjust - or "renumerate" parentid+childid to be gapless ? Is this a business requirement ? If yes, then the question is: do they really really need it ? Pleae ask them what is a real business vale of a "gapeless" sequence except that it looks priettier on the screen or on the report ? This is a very costly operation, it hits your preformance, and it's also errorprone, especially in multiuser enviroment - you need to consider many subtle interactions (locked records, deadlocks etc) between 2 or more users in your procedure.

Comment: Yes, this is a business requirement and not because it has to look pretty but to have a clean data set. There is only one user. Can you please help with the query?